# Memory allocation on pointers to non-pointers type of objects

Tags: c++, sharepoint, memory-management

I was wondering when I create a pointer e.g. a shared pointer on the heap

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<gDynamicBar> BarTest(new gDynamicBar());
```

and `BarTest` has as a member function an ordinary object `DynamicTexture` of the class Texture that holds an array of jpg images. Eg to load an image I have

```
BarTest->DynamicTexture.LoadImage("anImage.jpg");
```

Does this mean that everything is still allocated on the heap, despite the fact that `DynamicTexture` is not declared with the keyword `new`? Or do I have to make also sure that `DynamicTexture` is created as a new object within the `DynamicBar` class?

Answer (score 0):

The contained object is allocated inside the space of the containing object. If that is allocated on the free space (aka heap) the contained object is allocated on the heap.

Comment: Does this mean I do not ever need to create a new object on the heap within a class? Since it will be automatically allocated when I create my base class object with the keyword new?

Comment: How would you use new with a member object? You need a pointer to do that.